# Change priority(bandwidth) of network interface or by ip address

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ifconfig, metric

I have a virtual router with two networks. WAN and LAN. On LAN there are several PC's with fixed IP all on the same network. The router OS is Linux based.

Traffic from PC A would by default use all the bandwidth (over night or when my "work" machine is idle). But when I use my work PC I want to shape traffic in a way, that its traffic has higher priority so I don't get any lags or slow downloads on it even when PC A is still downloading.

How can I do that? Or is it better and easier to put the LAN PC's on different networks? I use nftables for firewalling.

Comment: Linux. Edited post.

Comment: Well, one questions is if I can do this by IP of the LAN PC or it is better to use multiple LAN interfaces.

Comment: Also the link is based on iptables and I use nftables. I doesnt look like "--set-tos" exists for nftables.

Comment: I think the relevant part is https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.cookbook.interactive-prio.html uses iptables